# Peewee ArrayField error

Tags: python, peewee

When I create my table based on a model without an ArrayField, I get no errors.

When I add:

```
images = ArrayField(CharField)
```

I get:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 5037, in create_table
    db.create_table(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3914, in create_table
    return self.execute_sql(*qc.create_table(model_class, safe))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3837, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3656, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 135, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3830, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: near "[]": syntax error
```

Can anyone point out why and provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What database driver are you using? ArrayField requires postgresql.